# My DPC++ program can't run on an intel ATS-P GPU. why?

Tags: c++, intel, intel-oneapi

The DPC++ code is very simple, just have a local array ,set the value of array be 0 and barrier mem.

```cpp
 #include <CL/sycl.hpp>
 using namespace sycl;
 #define WRAP_SIZE 32
 int main(){
    sycl::gpu_selector selector;
    queue exec_queue(selector);
    int num_blocks=128;
    int num_threads=256;
    int casBeg=0;
    int casEnd=2;

    auto device_mem=sycl::malloc_device(227000*sizeof(double),exec_queue);
    exec_queue.submit([&](sycl::handler& cgh)
    {
        sycl::stream out{ 4096, 128, cgh };
        auto sharedmem = sycl::accessor<int, 1, sycl::access_mode::read_write, sycl::access::target::local>(11, cgh);
        cgh.parallel_for(
            sycl::nd_range<1>(num_blocks * num_threads, num_threads),
            [=](sycl::nd_item<1> item_ct1) [[intel::reqd_sub_group_size(WRAP_SIZE)]] {
                int blkId = item_ct1.get_group(0);
                int tid = item_ct1.get_local_id(0);
                int stride = item_ct1.get_local_range().get(0);
                        out<<"inter\n";
                if (tid == 0)
                    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
                        sharedmem[i] = 0;
                item_ct1.barrier(sycl::access::fence_space::local_space);
            });
    }).wait();
    return 0;
 }
```

The build command is

```sh
dpcpp -DMKL_ILP64 -lmkl_sycl -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_tbb_thread -lmkl_core -pthread -std=c++17 -O0 -o <project_name> <code_name>.cpp
```

Compiled program can work ok on the P690 GPU, but not work on the NDK intel ATS-P GPU.
Why? Thx

Comment: I guess it is bit late. Can you post if this a compile-time or run-time error ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I have talked to intel engineers to feedback the problem. They will fix this issue.